# SQL Query: get data from multiple table with joining each other with common field but no guarantee any table have data for sure.

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to get data from multiple table with joining by common field but no table guarantees to have data in it.

Below example will clear the confusion :

**tableA**

```
 commonId       aName
   2              2AName
   5              5AName
   8              8AName
```

**tableB**

```
 commonId       bName
   3              3BName
   8              8BName
```

**tableC**

```
 commonId       cName
   1              1CName
   2              2CName
   3              3CName
```

from above available data we want data in following way:

```
commonId,   aName,      bName,      cName
  1          NULL        NULL        1CName
  2          2AName      NULL        2CName
  3          NULL        3BName      3CName 
  5          5AName      NULL        NULL
  8          8AName      8BName      NULL
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `full outer join`, and MySQL doesn't support that.  I would suggest approach this problem using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select commonId,
       max(aName) as aName, max(bName) as bName, max(cName) as cName)
from ((select commonId, aName, NULL as bName, NULL as cName
       from tableA
      ) union all
      (select commonId, NULL as aName, bName, NULL as cName
       from tableB
      ) union all
      (select commonId, NULL as aName, NULL as bName, cName
       from tableC
      )
     ) abc
group by CommonId;
```

This assumes that you do not have any duplicates in the tables.  If this is a possibility, you would need to explain what the results would look like in this case.

Comment: MAX will work properly for all dataType i.e string, int ....?

Comment: @murtaza.webdev . . . yes.